# SharePoint Server 2013 custom authenticator

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth

I need to develop an **authenticator for SharePoint 2013**, because I have to connect to it's SOAP interface through a CMIS client and the identity provided by the client should be checked against a custom identity server instead of an Active Directory domain. Is it possible? How can I do that?

I found a sample claim-based authentication [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg317440%28v=office.14%29.aspx). But this example implements a Forms-Based Authentication, while I have to authenticate the user through API.